# Java method with method with colon in parameter

Tags: java

I have been given a UML diagram for an abstract class Location. The class has one variable String name. It has the method addEmployee(employee : Employee): boolean.

The Employee class is associated to the Location class. Employee class has to variables String name and String address and methods getName():String and getAddress(): String

I am unsure about how to make the addEmployee method and I do not understand its parameter employee : Employee, what does the colon mean?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a type to me.

Comment: `:` means "of type". So `addEmployee(employee : Employee): boolean` means "method addEmployee taking an argument employee *of type* Employee, and returning a value *of type* boolean".

Answer (score 7):

The part after the colon describes the expected type of the parameter or method. So, in your example, the UML method

```
addEmployee(employee : Employee): boolean
```

would translate to the Java method

```
boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
}
```

Comment: You should select it as accepted answer since it solved your problem as far as I can see...

Answer (score 0):

You can read the colon to mean -  `the preceding returns a result of the following type` ,

So: `getName() : String`   means that getName() returns a result of type String

So the easiest one would be `getName()`

it may look like

```
public String getName(){

  /* FILL_IN_CODE_HERE */

}
```

Comment: thanks, i know that but what about the colon in the method addEmployee(employee : Employee), in the end this method should return a boolean but i wonder about the colon in the parameter addEmployee(employee : Employee)